# How to enable sudo from Jenkins SSH plugin?

Tags: jenkins, ssh, sudo

I tried running a `sudo` command from the `Jenkins` [SSH plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) but got the following error:

> sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo

My Jenkins job needs to be able to stop and start a service and I was [unable to enable the remote user to do it without sudo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399388/service-functions-without-sudo).

Is there any way to enable sudo-ing from Jenkins?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: people ask Jenkins questions all the time, which are not necessarily coding-related...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to enable `sudo` from `Jenkins` by changing `sudoers` on the remote host (SSH target) to not require `tty`:

```
#Defaults    requiretty
```